# Coloring by Closest Points, do they produce polygonal figures?

Tags: geometry

Consider a rectangle, and $k$ points with in that rectangle. Each of the $k$ points are colored distinctly from the other $k-1$ points. Let's call this set of colored points $K$. For every other point in the rectangle, color them with the same color as the closest point (Euclidean distance) in $K$. Essentially, the rectangle is broken apart to $k$ different figures, each having a different color. Are these figures guaranteed to be polygonal? I conjecture so, but I cannot find a proof. I've written a program to generate some rectangles for me and here is one with 7 points: [image: Partitioned Rectangle]
The cross-hairs are where each of $k$ points are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subdivision is called the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the point set, though it also has many other names.

Yes, the regions are polygonal. In fact, they are even *convex* polygons. The proof is simple. If the set of points is $P = \{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$, and the "cell" containing a point $p_k \in P$ is denoted by $C(p_k)$, then we have
$$
C(p_k) = \{ x : d(x,p_k) \le d(x,p_i) \text{ for }  i \ne k \} = \bigcap_{i\ne k} \{ x : d(x,p_k) \le d(x,p_i)\}
$$ 
The set $\{ x : d(x,p_k) \le d(x,p_i)\}$ is a half-space bounded by a straight line. In fact, the bounding line is the perpendicular bisector of the line from $p_k$ to $p_i$. The cell $C(p_k)$ is the intersection of a collection of these half-spaces, so it's a convex polygon.